# Having Issues with my Bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I've started working with LaTeX and everything is working and looks as I want. My only issue is that I would like to have a list of references with a couple of articles, websites and books in the end. I don't want them cited in the text, I just want them at the end as reference. I tried the command `\nocite{*}`, I tried `\printbibliography`. I have been googling and searching forums for hours but no solution suggestion has yet worked. I even tried doing it separately in a whole new document but that also didn't work. As I am new, I really don't know what to do next. Either anybody has a magical solution for me or I have to put them in manually. :-(
I don't know if it's because of the language issue (I have lots of Chinese in the doc).

This is how my preamble looks so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks, linkcolor = blue, citecolor = green, filecolor = blue, urlcolor =blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\def\tablenotes{\vskip2pt\footnotesize}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[main=ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{ctex}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style = alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}
```

And I tried this:

```
\begin{document}

...

\newpage
\section{Bibliography}
\begin{refsection}[Bibliographie]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Remove the `\begin{refsection}[Bibliographie]...\end{refsection}` and the `\section{Bibliography}`. You will have to compile your document with Biber. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains what Biber does. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can set up your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: Since you are new to LaTeX, you may want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 to get started with `biblatex`.